# BabelJS is processing the wrong files when working with Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4

I started from a configuration consisting of both webpack 3 and a similarly old babel version. It can be found in the following repo:

https://github.com/konradmi/react-loadable-ssr-code-splitting

I updated both webpack and babel to their latest versions, as well as all the node modules, and migrated the old configuration accordingly. This issue could stem from any of these.

Once I finished migrating, I noticed all the babel plugins traverse my webpack configs files (which are in a separate nested folder) instead of the actual js source files which are properly processed by webpack. (I verified it by doing some logging inside of the babel plugins).

The result is the same regardless of whether I'm using .babelrc or not.

The webpack config files used to be at the root of the project as you can see in the repo I linked to above, and now they are inside of a nested "config" folder.

At first I thought it might be the cause of this issue, so I tried the following:

- Using path.resolve() in the entry point in order to use an absolute path to make sure it wouldn't possibly be re-interpreted by babel from a string relative to who knows where.
- Putting the webpack config files back in the root of the project and building from that path.

In all the variations I've tried - webpack always does its job perfectly, while babel is traversing the wrong files. I'm not even sure how it's possible, babel-loader should be traversing the files which it got from the previous webpack rule, which emitted the correct files.

Here's my current Webpack 4 config files concatenated into 1 file and stripped of irrelevant rules and plugins for your convenience:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  name: 'server',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
  entry: './src/server.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')
  },
  mode: 'development',
  stats: 'verbose',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    '@babel/env',
                    {
                      'targets': {
                        'browsers': ['last 2 versions']
                      },
                      'debug': false
                    }
                  ],
                  '@babel/preset-react'
                ],
                plugins: [
                  '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                  '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                  '@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign',
                  'react-loadable/babel'
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually seeing that makes you say Babel is running on the wrong files? If someone wanted to look at your repo, what would they be looking for?

Comment: I'm logging in visitor: enter() the path in any of the plugins I'm providing to babel-loader. In the old repo I linked to the logs describe the source files (as they should), while with my new config the logs describe the webpack config files. Would you like me to create a repo with the new config as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was importing webpack in my server source code, the files babel was going over were webpack imports which I added there in the source code. It couldn't find anything else other than those imports because due to previous rules webpack was exporting a bundle with evals containing the processed code (dev mode settings). The babel plugin wasn't looking for eval statements, so the only thing I could see was the processing of webpack related imports.